# Can Alteryx workflows be triggered by changes in a database?

Tags: alteryx

I need to check for any new tables in a particular database and trigger Alteryx if there is one. The contents of the new table will have input parameters that Alteryx should be able to read.

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Dpends on the database.  However, you could always just schedule a job to run however often, and look at the database structure in order to process changes (e.g. from last run) as desired.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a(n iterative) macro in Alteryx, with the help of the CReW Macros, that checks a table for some condition then continues if it's true or pauses and tries again if it is not true.

I've made a workflow with such a macro that checks the maximum value of a date column against the max from a Modified field in a SharePoint list and only ran an update workflow if the SharePoint value ever became greater or equal to the one in the db.

The trick at that point is to match the maximum iteration time to the workflow's schedule. So if you have the pause tool wait for 5s and you have a max of 60 iterations, you can schedule the job to run every 5 min. In this case, at most, you'll have a sub-5-minute window where the source isn't being checked.

Answer (score 0):

Alteryx has no active listener facilities like that, as far as I'm aware.

The Alteryx Scheduler (you have to get it as a part of a larger product than just Designer) can however have scheduled jobs that will run a workflow on a period.

The other way I'm aware of you could do this, is a lot of RDBMS (MSSQL for instance) have notification services that you can setup to register and fire events inside of SQL server which you could use to execute an Alteryx workflow by command line. Oracle has a similar notification facility I don't recall the name of offhand.